# How to round off the below values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to round off the below values in SQL?

```
35.38
53.08
6.15
5.38
```

to

```
35.4
53.1
6.1
5.4
```

Comment: Use the SQL Round() function

Comment: didn't you ask a very similar question yesterday? Yep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(colname - 0.01, 1) AS RoundValue FROM TableName;
```

**SYNTAX OF ROUND():**

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f9d9/11

Comment: if i use this Round function i am getting the value 6.20 for the value 6.15, but the value i required is 6.10 lower bound

Comment: Check my answer now @GirishMulgund

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `round()`?

```
select round(val, 1)
```

However, I would recomend converting to a decimal format:

```
select cast(val as decimal(10, 1))
```

The `cast()` not only changes the *value*, but it also changes the *type*.  That means that tools should also print out only one decimal place.

Comment: please try searching before answering. it encourages help vampires

Comment: if i use this Round function i am getting the value 6.2 for the value 6.15, but the value i required is 6.1 lower bound

Comment: @GirishMulgund . . . The rules for rounding explicitly state that 6.15 would be rounded to 6.2.